# How to store SQLite DB on SD card?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdcard

I need to work with the database on SD card, if it's possible. If I use the code below, then the database is created on the internal storage (/storage/emulated/0):

```
private MyDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "xAPP"
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

How can I create a database on an SD card?

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory` gives you *internal* storage?

Comment: Yes, /storage/emulated/0

Comment: No, this decision does not suit me

Comment: Make sure you give runtime permission for `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: `How can I create a database on an SD card?`. In the same way as you do now on external storage. You have to find out the path to your apps private storage on the sd card. And knowing the path you can use the same code.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, found a solution.